# how to design the infinity in sqlite3 with sequelize and nodejs?

Tags: database, sqlite, sequelize.js, infinity, fastify

How should i define the infinity in my database.
i use

- nodejs
- fastify
- sequelize
- sqlite3

There are a few data should deal with:

- deadline: unlimited time or a date, type:string format:date
- usetimes: infinity  type:number

Do i need to change the type and validation to fix with the "infinity" words.such as:

```
//model

usetimes: {
    type     : DataTypes.Integer, ======> DataTypes.['string','Interger']
    allowNull: false,
   // validate : {
   //   min: -1
   // }
  },
```

when i change the type,how can i do the validation?
Please tell me how to deal with the infinity.

Comment: Infinity is not a value you can store. You need to define a domain set of values, like -1 means infinity in your application logic

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon  for  the date-type data like '2020-12-01' ，should i also define -1? but how can i validate this value.